# Filtering multiple models at a time with Next.js and Django Rest Framework

Tags: django-models, django-rest-framework, full-text-search, next.js13

I successfully implemented a search feature on a website I'm working on but I would like to know if there could be a more efficient way of doing this. Basically, typing in the search input field queries the database multiple times. Could there be a better way of optimizing the code?

#### Below is the search function in Next.js:

```
  const filterSearch = async () => {
    try {
      const courses_response = await fetch(`api/courses?query=${searchText}`, {
        method: "GET",
      });
      const articles_response = await fetch(
        `api/articles?query=${searchText}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
        }
      );
      const quicklinks_response = await fetch(
        `api/quicklinks?query=${searchText}`,
        {
          method: "GET",
        }
      );
      const courses_data = await courses_response.json();
      const articles_data = await articles_response.json();
      const quicklinks_data = await quicklinks_response.json();

      setCourses(courses_data);
      setArticles(articles_data);
      setQuickLinks(quicklinks_data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  };
```

#### The input field:

```
<div className="input-btn">
            <input
              name="search"
              type="search"
              placeholder="Search courses, articles and links"
              value={searchText}
              onChange={(e) => setSearchText(e.target.value)}
              autoFocus
            />
            <button onClick={searchQuery} className="btn-submit" type="button">
              <LiaSearchSolid />
            </button>
          </div>
```

#### Each of the three endpoints in Django looks like this:

`Views.py`

```
class QuickLinksView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuickLinkSerializer
    queryset = QuickLinks.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        search = self.request.query_params.get('query')
       
        if search != "" and search is not None:
         
            return QuickLinks.objects.all().filter(Q(title__icontains=search) | Q(excerpt__icontains=search)).distinct()
```

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to call QuickLinks.objects.all() twice:

```
class QuickLinksView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    serializer_class = QuickLinkSerializer
    queryset = QuickLinks.objects.all()

    def get_queryset(self):
        search = self.request.query_params.get('query')
       
        if search:
         
            return self.queryset.filter(Q(title__icontains=search) | Q(excerpt__icontains=search)).distinct()
```